# How to calculate a timely list of GPS points in a given radius in memory (Java)?

Tags: java, mongodb, gps, gis, postgis

I know this would be quite easy to do with PostGIS in a database, but I only expect my points to live for a couple of minutes max.

I would like to have a list of GPS points that live for 1-5min. When I add a new point, I would like to calculate a list of points from the aged list that are in a 1-10km radius of the new point.

It is still recommended to perform these operations in a database like PostGIS or Mongo?

If not, how would one go about calculating this in memory?

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use PostGIS?

Comment: @matthudson Given the dataset is very dynamic and not required to be persisted, doing this in memory seemed to be the best option

Comment: @b__ If i rephrase the question, I think it should be ok?

Comment: Given a choice, I'd dump my data into PostGIS and operate/aggregate there.

Comment: Would you choose PostGIS over Mongo?

Comment: Existing investment in PostgreSQL, if not also architectural preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute a quadkey, it's similar to a quadtree and bing maps use it for the tile server. A quadkey can be computed with a morton curve. You can download my php class hilbert-curve @ phpclasses.org.

Answer (score -1):

Databases are very slow, because they access slow disk memory.

For your solution, you need an indexing technic that Geo Spatial DBs uses, too, (PostGis or Oracle-Spatial). In your case your index stays in memory:

It is an (geo-) spatial index.
There are quad tree and R-Tree as state of the art. (sometimes  a kd-tree also is used)
Quad tree are easier to implement, R-Tree can be twice as fast than quadtrees. 
I would use the quad tree.

The most demanding part of your work is the delete operation of an point.
This is tricky and much slower than insert.

One solution, recomended by the original author of the quadtree, and which I would try: Mark the points as deleted, but keep them in the Quad tree.
Evry  x minutes rebuild the whole quadtree, by creating a new one from thedata of the old one but by only keeping the points still existing.

Once the points are in the quad tree, a range search is reduced only to points "nearby"

Comment: Thanks Alex, but my goal here is not to re-implement an in memory database. I would like to focus more on the GIS processing side.

Comment: This exactly is the answer, the quad tree it self has nothing to do with a database. But databases uses this kind of indexing, like you have to use too, if you want to avoid a brute force search over all points. Either do a brute force search or use a spatial index. There is no other solution.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't fully understand your answer initially